# How can I get refer to the statically known size and type of a literal array?

Tags: ats

For example,

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"

implement main0() =
        let
                var A = @[int](1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                val n = 5
                val what = "int"
        in
                println!("the array A contains ", n, " elements of type ", what)
        end
```

how could I define `n` and `what` with reference to `A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you could not because neither 'n' nor 'int' is
in the dynamic representation of A.